# How to use an auto generated filename while saving an EPS/JPG file in Octave5.2 (WINDOWS)?

Tags: octave, matlab-figure

I am using Octave. The code is:

```
    figure(1)
    plot(what ever i want)
    file_name = sprintf ("C:/Users/Admin/Dropbox/final/Uniaxial_trial_%d_%d.eps",nxt,nxb);
    print -color -depsc file_name
```

The above did not work. It generates a file with the name `file_name` and not the string stored in `file_name`

Answer (score 1):

It exists several syntax for `print`. Try:

```
print(file_name,"-color","-depsc")
```